# Testing Ionic 2 app on Android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2

I am trying to test my Ionic 2 app on an Android emulator. I have already added the Android platform and whitelisted the plugin. But when I run the coomand "ionic emulate android", it gives me the following errors:

[image]

I have been trying to solve that for almost 5 hours. Please help me guys.

Comment: plase try **ionic serve -l** and give me logs if error still persist...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like main.css and main.js cannot be found.

This usually indicates that there was a build error and the files could not be generated. You have to check your terminal log to see what error caused the issue.

Comment: I checked the logs, there was no error. Build finished with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

Comment: Try looking at the logs as you build it. The error should happen fairly early. When you see it, abort the build process by clicking CTRL+C

Comment: DId you ever try to run `ionic serve`? Does that work?

Comment: app was running great before build it for android. I was able to use ionic serve also visual studio ripple but now ionic serve isn't working to. basically, app isn't creating main.css and main.js. however, it creates pollyfils.js

Comment: If it doesn't create main.js and main.css you definitely have an error in your code. Again, please check the terminal output for errors. Even if it continues, make sure to scroll up until you find it. We won't be able to help you unless you post the exact error you get.

Comment: When that error happens, what is being shown in your android device?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you don't have Android Studio already installed or it's not properly configured.

Download the current version of Android and check